# How to add page number across master and subreports

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a requirment where I need to display current page number and the total page number accross reports. I have a master report and 2 subreports. I am not able to identify how to display the correct pagenumber across the master and subreports.
It would be great if u could help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open Ireport and Go to Window-> Palette option here you can see a Page number and total page element in tool category. Now just drag and drop into that location where you want to print page numbers.

Comment: Thank you Lucky for the answer. But Iam afraid the solution that you have given works only with simple report.I have realized that simple drag and drop does not work when we want the page number to be included even on subreport pages.Please let me know if I need to furnish some more information.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add a textfield to page footer in your main raport page, and the expression should be :  `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" /"` 
Then add other text field right next to the first one and the expression should be : `" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}`  This will look like this : 1 / 2 
But the important one is that;

1. set first text fields evaluation time: "**now**" from properties
   window.
2. set second text fields evaluation time: "**report**" from
   properties window.

Then, for viewing correctly these page numbers on subreport pages; 
Click and select your main report name at top of Report Inspector window on the left side. 
Make sure you checked and selected this option from properties window :

> Summary with Page Header and Footer

This will make your subreport show page numbers correctly. 
Make sure your subreport has summary band to get results.

*There is no need to pass parameters to subreport or even no need to add these textfields to subreport pages to show page numbers.*

Subreports will recognize page numbers automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $V{PAGE_NUMBER} variable, but in case of a sub-report it provides you either with just the current *sub-report* page number or with the total *sub-report* number of pages. The problem is that Jasper Reports doesn't straightly allow you to pass the current page number from the master report to the sub-report.

Simple solution would be if you just incorporate the functionality to print the current page number in the master report. This works but not in a flexible way since you loose the ability to manage the detail of printing the page number in each sub-report.

Eventually I've come up with the better solution utilizing scriptlets. The main idea is to pass to the sub-reports the scriptlet instance, containing the necessary information.

```
public class ExampleScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {
private Integer page_number;

public void afterPageInit() throws JRScriptletException {
    this.page_number = (Integer) this.variablesMap.get("PAGE_NUMBER").getValue();
}

public String getPageNum() throws JRScriptletException {
    return String.valueOf(page_number);
}

public ExampleScriptlet getScriptlet() throws JRScriptletException {
    return this;
}}
```

In the *master* report put `scriptletClass = "my.example.ExampleScriptlet"` in jasperReport tag.

In the sub-report section of the *master report* pass the instance of the scriptlet to the sub-report

```
<subreportParameter name="pg_num" ><subreportParameterExpression>
                $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.getScriptlet()
            </subreportParameterExpression> </subreportParameter>
```

Declare the scriptlet parameter in the *sub-report*

```
<parameter name="pg_num" class="my.example.ExampleScriptlet"/>
```

In the *sub-report* retrieve the page number from the scriptlet

```
 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["($P{pg_num}.getPageNum())"]]></textFieldExpression>
```