# JasperReport Pass Page Number To Subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport, page-numbering

I am passing page number information from my main report to a footer subreport.  In the main report, I have declared subreport parameters *pageTot* and *pageNum*.  They are mapped through the wizard to parameters from the main report *$V{PAGE* _ *COUNT}* and *$V{PAGE* _ *NUMBER}*. In the subreport, I have declared the two parameters *pageNum* and *pageTot*.  In their parameter properties, I have unchecked *use as a prompt*, and set them both as *java.lang.integer* types.  I then replaced the variables in the *text field expression* of the text fields to use the new parameter names *$P{pageNum}* and *$P{pageTot}*.  While this mapping is successful for the *pageNum* parameter, the *pageTot* parameter is not displaying the correct number.  For a 27 page test report, pages 1-26 say the total number of pages is 38.  The last page, 27, the total changes to 13.  I have also noticed that the original formulas were both mapped to *$V{PAGE* _ *NUMBER}*.  How can I get the correct number of pages for the total?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add page number across master and subreports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597256/how-to-add-page-number-across-master-and-subreports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was able to find:

```
$V{PAGE_COUNT}
    - The number of records that display on the page.
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} 
    - The page number.  When evaluated at 'now', you get the current page.
    - When evaluated at 'report', you get the last page, or total.
```

I could not find a way (iReport does not support) to evaluate a parameter at 'report' time, so I was not able to get the total number of pages to display.  I ended up moving this feature out of my SubReport and into the main report.