# page numbering in jasper studio reports with multiple dynamic pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 3 different **types** of pages in my jasper soft 5.6.2 studio report. The first is a mandatory jrxml page called "**Details"** which will always be only one and first page. Second is a dynamic page (is jasper but I can use jrxml if required) with a list of items **"Items"** page which can vary from 0 to several pages. Third is also a dynamic **"Comment"** page (is jasper but I can use jrxml if required)  which can vary from 0 to several pages.
I want to print page numbers like Page 1 of 5, page 2 of 5 and so on. Initially I had first two type of pages only that is no Comment page and my methodology worked, but with addition of third comment page it doesn't work anymore.

My Approach which worked: In the first page had a key attribute ='pageNumFrom' and 'pageNumTo' which I replaced in my java after calculating total pages. But for Items page I had variable PAGE_COUNT+1. 
With addition of third page this approach doesn't work because PAGE_COUNT variable is lost and new count starts for third page

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37552266/59087

Answer (score 0):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065376/3406242

This is a similar issue, and you should be able to resolve it in a similar manner by using the Master page numbering.